# Mudança de username no token OAUTH2

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth2, oauth

Tenho uma API Rest em spring com OAUTH2 minha duvida é a seguinte, é possivel eu mudar o username que é gravado no token de cada sessão do OAUTH2.
Meu problema basicamente é, que para facilitar o suporte o usuário admin consiga mudar de usuário a qualquer momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não é possível** e **nem deve ser feito dessa forma**.

O token gerado pelo servidor de autorização é imutável, ele é assinado e qualquer alteração em seu conteúdo irá invalidá-lo.

De qualquer forma, isso viola o padrão de autorização proposto pelo framework OAuth2, ao acessar recursos de outros usuários, eles devem estar cientes de que este acesso está sendo feito e autorizarem sua conta a realizá-lo.

Talvez o [Grant Type](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/) que você esteja utilizando não seja o mais adequado para o seu problema.

Comment: Conhece alguma forma que eu poderia fazer isso? Talvez uma senha mestre algo do tipo.

Comment: O ideal seria você ter um usuário admin, e autenticar utilizando este usuário. As funcionalidades do sistema devem permitir que este usuário permita verificar dados de outros usuários.

Comment: Como eu precisava realmente dessa função tendo em vista o atendimento mais facilitado do cliente, o que eu fiz, tenho uma rotina para pegar o usuario logado, fiz outra rotina quem com base no token criado para o admin eu aponto ele para outro usuario, Obrigado pelas ajudas e pelas dicas, abraço.